# Is my implementation of factorial method right?

Tags: java

I know how to calculate the factorial of a number but I'm not very skilled to move the implementation details into a method. Can you please tell me if my method is right?

```
public class Part3
    {
    public static void main (String args []) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        int factor=1;
        System.out.println("Enter a number to find the factorial of it: ");
        number= sc.nextInt();
    }
    public static int factorial (int number, int factor, int x)
    {
        if (number < 1 || number > 10)
            System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");
        else 
        {
            for(x=1; x<=number; x++ )
            {
                factor = factor*x;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The factorial of  "+x+" is = " +factor);
}
```

Comment: by functional do you mean recursion ?

Comment: Did you test this to see if it works? Did you ask your teacher what she/he means by Function Method?

Comment: You're going to have to better explain what you're asking. You already have a `factorial` function. What do you mean by "in a Function Method"? That is an... uncommon term, to say the least. Does the code produce the right output when you run it?

Comment: Basically, function is a method which returns one value. Basically i want to call the function

Comment: @KathyA or Henry Keiter, can u please go here http://prezi.com/6hsk6rgjqmi9/ics3u0-programming-4-methods/?utm_campaign=share&utm_medium=copy This prezi is made by my teacher, it tells u what function means

Comment: no it is not right, it should return int and it does not have return statement

Comment: Why does factorial take three parameters? Why don't you ever try to call factorial anywhere? Why doesn't factorial return anything? If you were going to call it, what would that call look like?

Comment: @user902383, yes u are right i am trying to do that

Comment: @DavidConrad that's what OP's asking. I guess my edit clears OP's motivation to post the question here.

Comment: @DavidConrad, is it supposed to be two parameters, int x and int number?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, thanks for making the question clear :)

Comment: @Bably other thing is, you dont need 3 arguments in your function, `number` is enough, set initial value of factor to be 1, initialize  `x` inside for loop, and return factor at the end function, and instead printing out invalid statement, just throw `InvalidArgumentException`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things:

- When you create a function you must return a value of that type always, you declared your method to return `int` so you must return an `int`, always (or you will get a compiler error).
- Also, you can declare variables inside your method, there's no need to pass all of them from your main.
- Don't forget to call your function in your main, otherwise it is not being used.

This would be the code

```
public class Part3 {
    public static void main (String args [])  {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        int factor=1;
        System.out.println("Enter a number to find the factorial of it: ");
        number= sc.nextInt();
        factor=factorial(number);
        System.out.println("The factorial of  "+number+" is = " +factor);
    }
    public static int factorial (int number) {
        int result = 1;
        if (number < 1 || number > 10)
            System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");
        else  {
            for(int x=1; x<=number; x++ ) {
                result= result*x;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: Luisluix, why did u do int result=1;

Comment: because its factorial, if i do 0, its not gonna work. also, inside your if you can return a -1 along with the message.

Comment: Also, please note that this will return 1 for invalid inputs*.

Comment: Luisluix, if i use your code, i get same error, as i did for Serge Ballesta.  FOR THIS LINE System.out.println("The factorial of  "+x+" is = " +factor); it says cannot find the variable x. i don't get it even tho we have declared it in the for loop?

Comment: change x to number, sorry forgot to change that println

Comment: luisluix, i get an error like for example if i do 11, its says invalid however, it also does the factorial for 11

Comment: check you parenthesis, you should add the parenthesis to your if:
if (number < 1 || number > 10){System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");}

just to be sure it isnt an identation error.

Comment: it doesn't work i have the code that u gave me, can u edit it?

Comment: are you getting a result for 11? or are you getting "1" as the factorial of 11?

Comment: i am getting the result for 11

Comment: any idea, for how to do it cuz i don't know how to do it, i tried everything

Comment: you can put the if in the main, and only call the function when it is between 1 and 10.... sorry im not much help right now im at work, cant compile/run code :/

Comment: public static int factorial (int number) , for this i add if, changing it into public static int factorial (int number, string if) {

Comment: I meant move the if statement out of the method.

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling the `public static int factorial (int number, int factor, int x)` anywhere . Here use this logic to come up with the functional/recursive code for finding n factorial

Any method declaration has the following parts:

**"Access modifier" "Data Type being returned" "Method name" (List of parameters)**

Refer to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) for more information

```
public int factorial(int n)
{
    return n * Factorial(n-1);
}
```

The above code will never stop . So you need a boundary condition for it. Try to come up with one. Happy coding !!

Comment: While this is a good example to explain recursion, I guess you should first cover how to declare and implement a method. Looks like OP is in learning phase and explain recursion w/o being able to declare and implement a method properly is not going to help for OP in the learning process because it would be a mix of concepts.

Comment: Also, methods in Java begin with a lower case letter by convention.

Answer (score 0):

int x parameter will always be overrided by for(x = 1... So this can be right.

BTW, to verify your method, create unit tests:

```
import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import org.junit.Test;

class Part3Test
{
    public static void testFactorial()
    {
        assertEquals(Part3.factorial(1, 1, 1), 1);
        assertEquals(Part3.factorial(2, 1, 1), 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm afraid your method is not very nice :-(

More seriously, you only use it as a static function, you declare it to return an int and you have no return statement. You pass 2 (input) parameters factor and x that are not used in the method.

If you want it to be a simple utility method without side effect nor usage of state attribute of an object, you could at least do :

```
public static int factorial (int number) // only one parameter
{
    int factor = 1; //the result - must be initialized to 1 since you use it later
    if (number < 1 || number > 10) {
        System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");
        factor = -1;
    }
    else 
    {
        for(int x=1; x<=number; x++ ) // x can be declared in the loop
        {
            factor = factor*x;
        }
    }
    return factor;
}
```

and use it that way :

```
    System.out.println("Enter a number to find the factorial of it: ");
    number= sc.nextInt();
    int factor = factorial(number);
    System.out.println("The factorial of  "+number+" is = " +factor); // print in the main
```

If you want to use it as a method that modifies the object you could try that :

```
public class Part3
    {
    private int factor;

    public static void main (String args []) 
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int number;
        Part3 part3 = new Part3(); // create an object
        System.out.println("Enter a number to find the factorial of it: ");
        number= sc.nextInt();
        part3.factorial(number)
        System.out.println("The factorial of  "+number+" is = " +part3.factor);
    }
    public void factorial (int number)
    {
        factor = 1; // already exists in the object
        if (number < 1 || number > 10) {
            System.out.println("Invalid!! the number has to be between 1 and 10");
            factor = -1;
        }
        else 
        {
            for(int x=1; x<=number; x++ ) // x can be declared in the loop
            {
                factor = factor*x;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "under u did a code" *gouges eyes out with melon baller*

Comment: Serge Ballesta for this line System.out.println("The factorial of  "+x+" is = " +factor); i get an error say cannot find symbol-variable x, if i do int x=0; and when i run the program and put 10 i get the right factorial for 10, however, 10 doesn't show up, only 0 shows up?

Comment: Serge Ballesta can u please help me, why is it giving me an error when x is already declared in the for loop?

Comment: *If you want to use it as a method that modifies the object you could try that* this is not the proper approach to solve this problem.

Comment: @Bably you should not accept a post if it gives problems. Only accept an answer if and only if it helped you the most and works as you expect.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, i am using the method that modifies the object, i am using the first code she gave me?

Comment: @Bably if that works with no problems and helped you to solve your problem (stated in the question) then accept it. If you still have questions/issues about this, then it would be better to not accept it unless it is clear. Also, make sure to provide a single question per post. If you have more questions that are not related to the question stated in the post, please create a new question. If you have questions about this post (answer), then post a new comment and ask about it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, i am asking only one question i didn't ask for any new questions?

Comment: @Bably my comment was in order to avoid generic further questions about this.